# Ordenar días con bucle

Tags: javascript

Tengo una variable (var dias), con los días de la semana invertidos: domingo, sábado, viernes...
con el bucle for tengo que regresar una cadena separada por comas y espacios con los días ordenados de forma correcta..

Comment: Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Comment: Otro consejo adicional a las dos lecturas que ya te recomendaron: realiza el [tour] para ganar tu primera medalla. También recuerda que pudes [edit] tu pregunta en cualquier momento para agregar más detalles.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con:

```
var dias = ["Domingo", "Sabado", "Viernes", "Jueves", "Miercoles", "Martes", "Lunes"];
var diasInv = dias.reverse().join(", ");
```

Con `reverse()` inviertes los elementos y con `join()` unes los elementos y los devuelves como una cadena, usando como separador el que indiques como parámetro, que es justamente lo que buscas.

---

Con un bucle `for` se me ocurre hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
var dias = ["Domingo", "Sabado", "Viernes", "Jueves", "Miercoles", "Martes", "Lunes"];
var str;

for (var i = dias.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    str += i != 0 ? dias[i] + ", " : dias[i];
}
```

Dentro del bucle he usado el `if ternario`, sería equivalente a escribir lo siguiente:

```
var dias = ["Domingo", "Sabado", "Viernes", "Jueves", "Miercoles", "Martes", "Lunes"];
var str;

for (var i = dias.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i != 0){
        str += dias[i] + ", ";
    }else{
        str += dias[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) no "separa" los elementos una lista. `.join()` **une** todos los elementos entre si y los devuelve como una cadena. Los elementos será unidos por un separador -que por defecto es `,`- pero puedes cambiar eso usando el parámetro opcional `separator` para especifícar un separador distinto que será colocado entre cada elemento.

Comment: Correcto ricardo-dlc. Lo escribí más para que lo entendiera y al final cometí un error, edito el comentario para no confundir a nadie. Gracias !

Comment: Hola, Fran. Gracias, pero se me pide que sea con bucle for, aunque -reverse()- me sirve, no es el método que puedo utilizar

Comment: Te he añadido a la respuesta como hacerlo con un bucle `for`. Espero te sirva `:)`